# Google chars doesn't appear with iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-visualization

I'm using MVC 4 for creating a web app.
In my web page I want to place a google chart (line chart) and an iframe to some external site.
I've taken the javascript code from the official documentation ([here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?hl=en))

So my code looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page";
}
@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', { packages: ['line'] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
        data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

        data.addRows([
          [1, 37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
          [2, 30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
          [3, 25.4, 57, 25.7],
          [4, 11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
          [5, 11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
          [6, 8.8, 13.6, 7.7],
          [7, 7.6, 12.3, 9.6],
          [8, 12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
          [9, 16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
          [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
          [11, 5.3, 7.9, 4.7],
          [12, 6.6, 8.4, 5.2],
          [13, 4.8, 6.3, 3.6],
          [14, 4.2, 6.2, 3.4]
        ]);

        var options = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
                subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
            },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
        };
        var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
}
    <h2>Page</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">
                <div id="linechart_material"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">
                <iframe id="videoiframe" src="https://www.google.com/starwars/" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is where it gets weird.
When I run the app, the chart isn't being rendered. However, once I've removed the iframe, it worked fine.
Has anyone encountered such issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this behavior is related with self closing tag: `<iframe ... />`, in that case `iframe` element is considered as missing a closing tag.

According to [XHTML 1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_3):

> Given an empty instance of an element whose content model is not EMPTY
>   (for example, an empty title or paragraph) do not use the minimized
>   form (e.g. use `<p> </p>` and not `<p /`>).

To summarize, in the specified example the JS chart is inserted on page after *non* closed `iframe` element. The solution would be to replace:

```
<iframe id="videoiframe" src="https://www.google.com/starwars/" />
```

with

```
<iframe id="videoiframe" src="https://www.google.com/starwars/"></iframe>
```